# Showing the elements in a dropdown list - JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem showing the elements from a dropdown list, which i have checkboxes inside, when I click the arrow to display the elements it shows the elements in the first dropdown but as I have two drops when I load in the second it shows the elements of the drop from above. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cascade.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="pesquisas.js"></script>
        <title>Pesquisa de Imóveis</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1"><!--"dropdown-check-list"-->
                                <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list1')">Anúncio</span><!--"anchor"-->
                                <ul id="items" class="items">
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor1>Aluguer</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor2>Venda</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor3>Compra</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor4>Permuta</input></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list">
                                <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements('list2')">Imóveis</span>
                                <ul id="items" class="items">
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor1>Apartamento</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor2>Moradia</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor3>Armazém</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor4>T4</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor5>Terreno</input></li>
                                    <li><input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor6>Loja</input></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    .dropdown-check-list {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 20%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
    right: 8px;
    top: 21%;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
    padding: 2px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

And here is my javascript function:

```
    function getElements(list) {
    var checkList = document.getElementById(list);
    var items = document.getElementById('items');
    checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
        if (items.classList.contains('visible')) {
            items.classList.remove('visible');
            items.style.display = "none";
        }

        else {
            items.classList.add('visible');
            items.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript function as below:

```
function getElements(list) {
    var checkList = document.getElementById(list);
    var items = document.getElementById(list + '_items');

    if (items.classList.contains('visible')) {
        items.classList.remove('visible');
        items.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        items.classList.add('visible');
        items.style.display = "block";
    }

};
```

and update your HTML code:

```
...
<ul id="list1_items" class="items">
...
...
<ul id="list2_items" class="items">
...
```

here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jr8yyqf/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Both of your lists have the same id, which is invalid and explains why you always toggle the same list. You could probably simplify alot by using event.target and querySelector.

```
<span class="anchor" onclick="toggle()">text</span>

var toggle = function toggle( event ) {
    var list = event.target.querySelector('.items');
    if (list.classList.contains('visible')) {
        list.classList.remove('visible');
        list.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        list.classList.add('visible');
        list.style.display = "block";
    }        
}
```

Comment: why do you say that my lists has the same id? i assigned different id's for the two drops, drop1 = list1 drop2=list2, and then i passed the id by parameter

Comment: Did you get an error? Explain to me why you are adding click events to the lists then, since I didn't understand what you were doing with the `checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = ` part. Try changing your original code then to unique ids and figure out what you're trying to do with the 3 different getElementByX things.

Comment: `<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1">
...
<ul id="items" class="items">
...
</ul>
</div>
<div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list">
...
<ul id="items" class="items">
...
</ul>
</div>` Both your <ul> elements have the same id and since you're selecting the list by id, the getElementById will always return the first <ul> element.

Comment: In your code I get an error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"